Translation help with HaEmek Davar
On Genesis 21:26, in reference to Avimelech claiming he didn't know who stole Avraham's wells.
לא ידעתי מי עשה. לא התנצל לומר לא ידעתי מזה אלא לא ידעתי מי עשה וגו׳ שהרי עיקר ההוכחה הוא על אשר נעשה גזלה ע״י עבדי אבימלך ע״ז השיב שלא ידע מי עשה הגזלה. אולי בא אדם קטן בשם עבדי אבימלך ושיקר:
Who is "and he lied" referring to -- to Avimelech's claim of innocence, or to the purported nobody who says he represents the king?

Sounds like the latter

According to Rabbi Cooperman's explanations [https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=59392&st=&pgnum=297&hilite=] it is referring to someone else who is not of Avimelech's entourage.

Yes, the latter. "Wasn't my people as far as I know. And if someone showed up and claimed they were acting in the name of the crown, that proves nothing as it's possible they were lying." (I think the most likely situation is that Avimelech had not given the orders, was not aware of his people doing it ... but also realizes they may have done so on their own, possibly even justifying it to themselves as "the kind of thing he would want us to do." So he sounds a bit defensive.)

@Shalom it is hard to conclude that Avimelekh speaks truthfully. He called himself Tzadik(!) after abducting Sarah. I would stop at translation as you suggest and not hypothesize if he ordered it or not. We see in stories of Avraham and Yitzchak that pilishtim always reported about Avos to the king and refrained to deal with them directly on their own. See here discussion about the wells and why they were closed. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/146088/36610

There's a big difference between "lying" and "bending over backwards in self-justification."
